# Should delta.yaml be committed to git?

Tags: projectconfig, git, project.yaml

Getting started with CraftCMS 3.1's [project config files](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/project-config.html) and I can't find any documentation about whether `storage/config-deltas/delta.yaml` should be committed to git

Answer (score 2):

No, you would not check these files into Git.

I have a `.gitignore` rule to just ignore everything in `storage/` and so I treat it as a cache directory.

Which it is... except for the unfortunate fact that any rebrand (logo, icon) files are stored in `storage/` as well. But I just manually add them in via `git add -f`

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. At some point a `.gitkeep` file appeared in storage/config-deltas/ without any documentation of whether only the folder was necessary or the file. I'll gitignore `delta.yaml` — thanks for your help!

Comment: Can I just delete all delta files in storage/config-deltas in my development environment?
Are the delta files just temporary to speed things up? Or are they needed to build up the project config?

Answer (score 1):

Just stick with the `.gitignore` of Craft.

https://github.com/craftcms/craft/blob/main/storage/.gitignore

I assume it's better to commit the folder, as `config-deltas` is not in the official `.gitignore`.